What is the symbol of deliverance that Wisdom 16:6 speaks of?
We read in Wisdom of Solomon 16:5-6 ( NRSV):

For when the terrible rage of wild animals came upon your people
and they were being destroyed by the bites of writhing serpents,
your wrath did not continue to the end;they were troubled for a little while as a warning,
and received a symbol of deliverance to remind them of your law's command.

Now, the bronze  figure of serpent that Moses erected was meant as a symbol of deliverance from snake bite that had immediately preceded ( Numbers 21:4-8)  But, was a symbol of deliverance against wild animals given to Israel ? Or, does Wisdom categorise serpent as wild animal ? Or, does the Verse refer to the sign of circumcision ( Gen 17:10-11)  ?
My question in sum,  is : What  is  the symbol of deliverance  that Wisdom 16:6 speaks of?

It is just Hebrew poetry. They wrote about something in two ways to deepen the meaning. As you already guessed, the bronze serpent is the symbol.

Thanks, ארקדיוס. Hope you will come up with a detailed answer.

The symbol of deliverance is indeed the Bronze Serpent that Moses made. The stanza in question is a case of poetic parallelism, frequently used in Hebrew poetry:

[a]the dire venom of beasts came upon them
and [b] they were dying from the bite of crooked serpents

The poet here uses two phrases to convey the same thought, much as the author of Psalm 25 did when he wrote:

[a] Make known to me your ways, Lord;
[b] teach me your paths.

So, yes, the author here categorizes serpents as a type of wild beast. No separate sign was given for other wild beasts, nor is the writer speaking of circumcision.
